# Is there any denomination which teaches that God never commanded burnt offerings and sacrifice to Israel?

Tags: jeremiah

> Jeremiah 7:22
>
> A. New International Version
>  For when I brought your ancestors out of
>   Egypt and spoke to them, I did not **just** give them commands about burnt
>   offerings and sacrifices
>
> B. English Standard Version
>  For in the day that I brought them out of
>   the land of Egypt, I did not speak to your fathers or command them
>   concerning burnt offerings and sacrifices.

If all translations like A, there is no question. But there are quite many other translations (besides ESV) which like B where it leads to a conclusion that burnt offerings and sacrifices are traditions. Burnt offerings can be seen in Cain/Abel and Noah story.

Assuming that the correct translation is something like B, is there any denomination who interpret as it read in B ?

Comment: I think God's point was that He dealt with Israel without sacrifices at some specific point in time, (7:22a) but had a separate, particular 'covenant' with them (7:23) during their exodus. Not that He *never* commanded sacrifiecs to be made. (e..g He did *after* this period, Ex 3:12).

Comment: @SolaGratia, verse 23 _but I gave them this command: Obey me, and I will be your God and you will be my people. **Walk in obedience to all I command you**, that it may go well with you._ To me it's quite strange, as in our daily sentence might become something like this : _in the day that I brought them out of the land of Egypt I did not command them to do burnt offerings, but to obey Me to all I command them later on which one of My commands is to do burnt offerings_. Me : (???) :)

Comment: If you read it in context, God is saying his only law was not to expect sacrifices or especially difficult or toilsome works, but just a proper attitude toward God. They couldn't even do that. I believe contextually, this is the gist.

Comment: @SolaGratia, _"his only law was not to expect sacrifices or especially difficult or toilsome works"_  this is the one of what I think and I hold where this can be concluded from the verse in NIV version :).

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. The closest we get is the Marcionites, a Gnostic sect who rejected the Old Testament and believed the God of the Israelites was a different and inferior god to the god of the New Testament.

Nevertheless, this question would never rise or fall on the translation of Jeremiah 7:22 since there are tons of extended passages in the Old Testament where God does prescribe burnt offerings and sacrifices.

The ESV translation is getting at the fact that God is mainly angry that his voice has not been heeded, not that he hasn't had enough sacrifices. His evidence is that when the Israelites came out of Egypt, he didn't give them any instruction about sacrifices until they made it to Siani. His only requirement was that they would follow his voice and obey him.